# Too many open files error when reading from a directory

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using readTextFile(/path/to/dir) in order to read batches of files, do some manipulation on the lines and save them to cassandra.

Everything seemed to work just fine, until I reached more than 170 files in the directory (files are deleted after a successful run).
Now I'm receiving "IOException: Too many open files", and a quick look at lsof I see thousands of file descriptors opening once I run my code.
Almost all of the file descriptors are "Sockets".

Testing on a smaller scale with only 10 files resulted in more than 4000 file descriptors opening, once the script has finished, all the file descriptors are closed and back to normal.

Is it a normal behavior of flink? should I increase the ulimit?

Some notes:
The environment is Tomcat 7 with java 8, flink 1.1.2 using DataSet API.
Flink job is scheduled with quartz.

All those 170+ files sum to about ~5MB.

Comment: Can you add the information which version of Flink you are using? Also, are you using the DataSet or the DataStream API? Thanks

Comment: Flink 1.1.2 using DataSet API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

After narrowing the code, I found out that using "Unirest.setTimeouts" inside a highly parallel "map()" step caused too many threads allocations which in turn consumed all my file descriptors.